# How to avoid Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field from springBoot application

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, jpa

> I call an interface in my controller class, First of all I declare
> the interface by using @Autowired annotation in my controller
> class,When I run my application it throws an exception below type

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'managerController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'transactionRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionRepository' defined in com.nilmani.workload.repository.TransactionRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract long com.nilmani.workload.repository.TransactionRepository.pendingMaterial(long,long)! Reason: Validation failed for query for method public abstract long com.nilmani.workload.repository.TransactionRepository.pendingMaterial(long,long)!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract long com.nilmani.workload.repository.TransactionRepository.pendingMaterial(long,long)!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:659) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at com.nilmani.workload.WorkLoadApplicationKt.main(WorkLoadApplication.kt:12) ~[main/:na]
```

> ManagerController.kt

```
package com.nilmani.workload.controller

import com.nilmani.workload.entity.*
import com.nilmani.workload.model.request.EmployeeRequest
import com.nilmani.workload.model.request.ReqDepositMaterial
import com.nilmani.workload.model.request.ReqUpdateWithdrawMaterial
import com.nilmani.workload.model.request.ReqWithdrawMaterial
import com.nilmani.workload.model.response.*
import com.nilmani.workload.repository.DepositRepository
import com.nilmani.workload.repository.EmployeeRepository
import com.nilmani.workload.repository.TransactionRepository
import com.nilmani.workload.repository.WithdrawMaterialRepository
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
class ManagerController {
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var employeeRepository: EmployeeRepository
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var withdrawMaterialRepository: WithdrawMaterialRepository
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var depositRepository: DepositRepository
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var transactionRepository: TransactionRepository

 /**Update the WithDrawMaterial table*/
   @PostMapping("/updateTransaction")
    fun updateWithdrawMaterial(@ModelAttribute request: ReqUpdateWithdrawMaterial):ResponseEntity<*>{
        val existingUser = employeeRepository.findById(request.userId)
        if (existingUser.isPresent){
            val existWork = withdrawMaterialRepository.findById(request.withDrawId)
            return if (existWork.isPresent){
                val pendingNearUser = TransactionMaterial(
                    userId = request.userId,
                    withDrawId = request.withDrawId,
                    material = request.material,
                    depositId = request.depositId,
                    pending = transactionRepository.pendingMaterial(request.withDrawId,request.depositId)
                )
                val saveMaterial = transactionRepository.save(pendingNearUser)
                return ResponseEntity(saveMaterial,HttpStatus.OK)
            }else{
                ResponseEntity(ResMessage("you need to learn then we provide work you"),HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
            }
        }else{
            return ResponseEntity(ResMessage("You are not a registered User ! Register First"),HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE)
        }
    }
}
```

> TransactionRepository.kt

```
package com.nilmani.workload.repository

import com.nilmani.workload.entity.TransactionMaterial
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Modifying
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam

interface TransactionRepository :JpaRepository<TransactionMaterial,Long> {
 @Query("SELECT  WithdrawMaterial .quantity,DepositMaterial .totalDeposit,WithdrawMaterial .quantity-DepositMaterial .totalDeposit  FROM WithdrawMaterial  INNER JOIN DepositMaterial ON WithdrawMaterial .id = DepositMaterial .withDrawId")
    fun pendingMaterial(@RequestParam("withDrawId") withDrawId:Long,@RequestParam("depositId")depositId:Long):Long

}
```

> I declare everything properly,Why I am getting such type of exception
> I am using IntleIj community version 21.2, mac os ,

Comment: What are you trying to do with the `@RequestParam` in `fun pendingMaterial(@RequestParam("withDrawId") withDrawId:Long,@RequestParam("depositId")depositId:Long):Long
`? I think this annotation is not suppose to be used here and that's what's breaking the runtime dependency validation.

Comment: Reason for  pass the parameter WithdrawId and depositId that both contain whole row data ,so it is easy to track the material  taken and deposit by the worker ,So I define the @RequesParam inside JPA repository

Comment: The exception tells you already what is wrong. `Validation failed for query for method public abstract long com.nilmani.workload.repository.TransactionRepository.pendingMaterial(long,long)!`. The query isn't a valid JPQL query. Nor is your method a valid JPA repository method, what is the `@RequestParam` annotation doing in there? Nor are you even using those method arguments in your query.

Comment: When I run this query in sql bench editor this query works fine  and return the result as per my requirement,But when I pass the parameters inside the pendingMaterial() with the help of @Requestparam it throws null pointer exception and above exception that I Mentioned in my question. What is the reason for this issue, In entity class I provide default value to all the data members,

Comment: Have you actually **read** my comment. I stated it isn't a valid **JPQL** query, I didn't say anything about **SQL** as you told the `@Query` it is a JPQL not SQL. `@RequestParam` is just plain wrong here and you aren't using those parameters in the query at all.